# Java try-catch diferencia entre colocarlo afuera o adentro de un ciclo

Tags: java, bucles, try-catch

Estaba programando y el IDE me hizo una sugerencia sobre el siguiente código

```
while (!this.socket.isClosed())
    ...resto del código...
```

Me sugirió cambiarlo a lo siguiente pues el método `isClosed` del objeto `socket` lanza una excepción:

```
while (true) {
    try {
        if (!!this.socket.isClosed()) break;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        ...manejo de la excepción...
    }
    ...resto del código...
}
```

En principio me sacó de onda, pero me fijé bien y en efecto, ese código tiene el mismo efecto que se obtendría con el siguiente código (o por lo menos eso quiero pensar):

```
try {
    while (!this.socket.isClosed())
        ...resto del código...
} catch (IOException e) {
    ...manejo de la excepción...
}
```

**¿Existe alguna diferencia significativa entre lo que el IDE me sugirió y como yo pensaba hacerlo?**

Mi hipótesis (basada en meras suposiciones) es que al poner el try catch dentro de un ciclo se ejecutará cada vez que se ejecute el ciclo, a diferencia de ponerlo afuera del ciclo, que se ejecutará mientras el ciclo esté "vivo" o su condición se cumpla.

Seguramente el compilador o la JVM optimicen el código para que al final no exista diferencia entre hacerlo de una forma u otra, pero me gustaría salir de esa duda, espero me puedan asesorar.

Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los IDE no siempre aciertan al refactorizar código automaticamente en estos casos, por ejemplo lo que ha hecho en este punto:

```
if (!!this.socket.isClosed()) break;
```

es totalmente absurdo, pues la doble negación `!!` es equivalente a no tener ninguna negación!

Lo que te quería indicar el IDE probablemente fuese que necesitabas añadir la excepción, y ha buscado una manera de meterla un poco extraña *(para mi gusto)*, pues los bucles `while(true)` no son lo más "*correcto*", dado que cuando el contenido del mismo crece, buscar la condición de salida (el `break`) puede ser complicado, condición que con

```
while(!this.socket.isClosed())
```

se ve mucho mejor (O con cualquier otro flag, dado el caso).

---

Por lo demás, meter el try/catch **dentro** o **fuera** del bucle ***no tiene mayores implicaciones respecto a la optimización***, pues si no hay excepciones a la hora de ejecutar el código el compilador los "ignora".

Como prueba de esto dejo el siguiente enlace a una [respuesta de la versión inglesa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/149610/14083367) donde se discute la viabilidad de tener el try/catch dentro o fuera del bucle.

---

### Entonces, da igual dónde pongamos el try/catch?

**No!**

- Un ***try/catch con un bucle dentro*** del bloque try detendrá la ejecución del bucle si se lanza una excepción, es decir, ***se sale del bucle tras la excepción!***.
- Al contrario, un ***bucle con un try/catch dentro*** del bucle ***continuará la ejecución del bucle tras la excepción*** como si no hubiese pasado nada.

En definitiva, dónde lo metas dependerá un poco de lo que necesites hacer cuando ocurra la excepción